# React typer component

Tags: beginner, react.js, animation, jsx

I'm fairly new to JS and have been learning react this week. Struggling to properly understand the `useEffect` and `useState` but think I'm getting there.

I do however think that my use of `useRef` isn't the right way of doing things and am looking for an experts view on what I have written.

The goal is to write an animated typer that has a human-like feel to the typing with errors etc, while having a fixed rate blinker at the end.

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

const alp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")
const newmin = 25
const newmax = 45

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

function Flasher(flash) {
    const [flashval, updateFlash] = useState("<span>&nbsp&nbsp</span>")
    useEffect(() => {
        if (flash) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (flashval === "&nbsp|") {
                    updateFlash("<span>&nbsp&nbsp</span>")
                } else {
                    updateFlash("&nbsp|")
                }
            }, 375)
        }
    })
    return (<>
        {parse(flashval)}
    </>)
}

export default function Typer({text, transform, flash, speed = 1}) {


    const options = useRef(text.split("|"))
    const [display_text, updateTxt] = useState("")
    let index = useRef(0)
    let min = useRef({"now":newmin, "next":newmin})
    let max = useRef({"now":newmax, "next":newmax})

    useEffect(() => {

        //get the full text required
        let current_full_text = options.current[index.current];
        let text_current
        min.current.next = newmin
        max.current.next  = newmax
        //check if should do error or not make error
        if(randomIntFromInterval(1,10)===1){
            text_current = current_full_text.substring(0, display_text.length) + alp[randomIntFromInterval(0, alp.length-1)]
            min.current.next = 120
            max.current.next  = 255
        }else if(display_text !== current_full_text.substring(0, display_text.length)){
            text_current = current_full_text.substring(0, display_text.length-1)
            min.current.next = 60
            max.current.next = 90
        }else{
            //set the current text +1
            text_current = current_full_text.substring(0, display_text.length + 1);
        }

        // logic if need to switch text or not
        if (text_current === current_full_text) {
            // this will wait at the end of each word
            index.current++;
            min.current.now = 300;
            max.current.now  = 400;
            text_current = "";
            // increases the index of the array and if too many then it resets to 0 and reset current text
            if (index.current > options.current.length - 1) {
                index.current = 0;

            }
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            updateTxt(text_current);
        }, randomIntFromInterval(min.current.now, max.current.now) * 10 * speed)

        min.current.now = min.current.next
        max.current.now = max.current.next
        // ;
    })

    return (<><span>{display_text}</span><Flasher flash/></>)
    //
}
```

use like this

```
<Typer speed="0.5" flash={true} text="This is my test typer |I type, therefor I am "/>
```